# Inter-connect two active directories for sharepoint authentication

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, sharepoint-2010, windows-authentication

I have 1 server with windows 2003 which is our office's domain controller, and other server with windows server 2008 in another office.

The domain names are different, and what i need to do, is interconnect both active directories, to authenticate (for example) with domain1 credentials on domain2.

I have a sharepoint 2010 in server2 (outside office) so, it will work if i can login in sharepoint using credentials from Active directory1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set up a trust between the two domains.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need network connectivity between the two (i.e. a site-to-site VPN tunnel), then you'd need to setup a trust between the two domains.

Per [the technet article on domain trusts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816810%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) a trust between a 2003 domain and a 2008 domain is possible, presuming both domains are at the minimum forest functional level are at Windows Server 2003.

For your initial request, to be able to authenticate DOMAIN1 users to DOMAIN2, and DOMAIN 2 users to DOMAIN1, you'd want to set up a two-way trust.